# Query date from a column with alphabet

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a query for getting date range in oracle.But the problem is the column contain prefix with date value
E.g (AA 2018-02-01)

```
Table 
Id column1 column2
1  XX      AA 2018-01-02
2  YY      BB 2018-02-01
3  ZZ      CC 2018-03-01
4  XZ      DD 2018-04-01
```

I want to get data for the date range jan to march.
I want using select query and not using pl/sql query.

Comment: the posizion of 'column2' does not make sense. can you format this properly

Answer (score 3):

```
with testdata as
(select 'XX' column1, 'AA 2018-01-02' column2 from dual union all
 select 'YY' column1, 'BB 2018-02-01' column2 from dual union all
 select 'ZZ' column1, 'CC 2018-03-01' column2 from dual union all
 select 'XZ' column1, 'DD 2018-04-01' column2 from dual)

select column1,
       column2,
       to_date(substr(column2,4),'YYYY-MM-DD') date_column
from testdata;
```

All you have to do is use a substr combined with to_date using a date format string that matches the data. Running the above query produces these results:

```
column1     column2         date_column
XX          AA 2018-01-02   02-JAN-18
YY          BB 2018-02-01   01-FEB-18
ZZ          CC 2018-03-01   01-MAR-18
XZ          DD 2018-04-01   01-APR-18
```

If you are just trying to limit to only January through March, you could do something like this:

```
select column1,
       column2,
       to_date(substr(column2,4),'YYYY-MM-DD') date_column,
       extract(month from to_date(substr(column2,4),'YYYY-MM-DD')) date_month
from testdata
where extract(month from to_date(substr(column2,4),'YYYY-MM-DD')) between 1 and 3;
```

Results:

```
column1     column2         date_column     date_month
XX          AA 2018-01-02   02-JAN-18       1
YY          BB 2018-02-01   01-FEB-18       2
ZZ          CC 2018-03-01   01-MAR-18       3
```